# Change btrfs default subvolume in order to delete snapshot

Tags: linux, btrfs, snapshot

I have used [snapper](http://snapper.io/) with Fedora 26 to create snapshots of my btrfs system, and I am trying to start fresh (i.e. remove snapper and anything it has done) but I have one snapshot I cannot remove as it appears to be my default subvolume (I don't remember why it would have done this, perhaps I tried a rollback).

```
# snapper delete 535
Deleting snapshot failed.
# btrfs subvolume get-default /
ID 1630 gen 112224 top level 275 path .snapshots/535/snapshot
# btrfs subvolume show /
/
    Name:                   root
    UUID:                   544f9215-4537-fe4b-b1b5-4da21d9abb9c
    Parent UUID:            -
    Received UUID:          -
    Creation time:          2017-07-19 21:28:42 +0100
    Subvolume ID:           257
    Generation:             112591
    Gen at creation:        8
    Parent ID:              5
    Top level ID:           5
    Flags:                  -
    Snapshot(s):
```

I am not certain if what I am asking here makes sense, but I want to change my default subvolume back to the parent (;master;root, not sure the right word) volume I had when I originally set up the system at the top-level of the file system, i.e. /, before the default change.

```
# btrfs subvolume list / -a -p -t
ID      gen     parent  top level       path
--      ---     ------  ---------       ----
257     112604  5       5               <FS_TREE>/root
258     112604  5       5               <FS_TREE>/home
263     112214  257     257             root/var/lib/machines
275     112593  257     257             root/.snapshots
276     112577  258     258             <FS_TREE>/home/.snapshots
1630    112224  275     275             <FS_TREE>/root/.snapshots/535/snapshot
1639    112604  257     257             root/var/log
1641    111548  257     257             root/mnt/virtualbox
```

Can I run a `btrfs subvolume set-default` to one of these to achieve this. I'm not certain on the meaning of /... as I was guessing I should change the default to the root with ID 257, but this threw me off.

The files inside this snapshot are now outdated compared to those in / and so I am not looking to overwrite / with the contents of the snapshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With mounting a BTRFS filesystem, it's possible to specify which subvolume to mount, or not:

> A Btrfs filesystem has a default subvolume, which is initially set to
>   be the top-level subvolume [who's ID is always 5] and which is mounted if no subvol or
>   subvolid option is specified. - https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Snapshots

You can override the default subvolume by using the `subvol` option when mounting the filesystem:

```
mount /dev/sda / -o subvol=root/.snapshots/535/snapshot
```

In your case, subvolume 275 was changed to be the default when you performed a rollback.

> rollback [options] [number]
>
> Creates two new snapshots and sets the default subvolume. *Per default the system boots from the default subvolume of the root
>   filesystem.* - http://snapper.io/manpages/snapper.html

What the Snapper map page is saying here implicitly is that it expects the mount point for your root filesystem to **not** specify a subvolume. Otherwise the rollback command would have no effect since it would be overwritten by the `subvol` option.

Your original default subvolume was the top-level (ID 5). You can certainly use `btrfs subvolume set-default` to make it the default again, but... perhaps you shouldn't.

If you've been booting from your 535 subvolume, then perhaps you've accumulated a vast number of changes over time on that subvolume. Reverting to your top-level subvolume would mean the *loss* of those changes; I'm using the word *loss* loosely here given that the changes would still exist, just in a different subvolume.

Comment: I did `set-default` to ID `257` subvolume and I was then able to delete the snapshot. All my changes since ID `275` was created and made default did not appear in that subvolume but in my root and so fortunately I didn't have to shuffle things around to recover 'lost' changes. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the same problem. When you say "loss of changes", in what situation does that happen? My root was subvolume 5. I rolled back to subvolume 685. I'm now on subvolume 1017, but mount sets "subvolid=1017,subvol=/@/.snapshots/685/snapshot" so I can't delete subvolume 685. As there are snapshot subvolumes after 685 and 685 was based on 5 then what might break if I "set-default 5 /"? Aren't snapshots built on each other so an older base for a newer snapshot should be fine? Thanks.

Comment: Just missed the edit deadline. Actually, I've got snapshot 685, which is btrfs subvolume ID 1017. Mount says "subvolid=1017,subvol=/@/.snapshots/685/snapshot" despite there being newer snapshots at boot time. If snapshots are built on each other and I've got newer snapshots than my current default, what would I lose by setting my original subvolume as default? I'm asking because I've got 10GB in root, 18GB used, and 4.9GB "excl" usage on the old base subvolume.

Comment: Actually, BTRFS snapshots don't depend on each other. For example, in Docker when images/layers are built on each other it creates dependencies between the layers; The upper layers depend on the lower ones. That's not the case in BTRFS. In BTRFS, subvolumes *share* blocks of data. For example, if subvolume B is a snapshot of subvolume A, that just means that (at the time of creation) B points to the same data as A. You can in fact delete snapshot A and B would remain unaffected. I don't quite grasp the specifics of your question, IBBoard, but perhaps this can help you intuit how it works.